# navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition() is not getting a response from googleapi

Tags: reactjs, navigator, w3c-geolocation

I am using react to get geolocation on localhost:3000. I have seen another person get the geolocation coordinates on their localhost, but I am unable to do so even with allow location access enabled on Chrome.

I have tried using both the hooks and class syntax in react. I have enabled allow access. I eventually used an ip address api to get a general location, but since the geolocation is supposed to work(at least that is what I have been told) I would at least like to see it work so I can implement it with https in the future. The error log does not even get fired, whereas the first three logs are getting fired when the component is mounted. Here is the code I have tried, I have made it as simple as possible:

```
const App = props => {

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('hello')
    console.log(navigator)
    console.log(navigator.geolocation)
    if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
        console.log(position)
      }, (error) => {
       console.log(error)
      })
    } else {
      console.log('error')
    }
  }, [])
  return (
      <div>
        <h3>Please Login.</h3>
      </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

I expect to receive a response from googleapi.

Edit:

I added the error callback and it printed:

message: "Network location provider at 'https://www.googleapis.com/' : No response received."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the optional error callback to handle the error (if user declines location permission)

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success[, error[, [options]])
```

you are checking only if it is in navigator or not !!!

if user declines location permission then error callback will handle it...

possible options are (reference taken from mdn)

```
{
  enableHighAccuracy: true, 
  maximumAge        : 30000, 
  timeout           : 27000
}
```

Comment: it doesn't need two parameter, those are optional parameters. `(success[, error[, [options]])`

Comment: yes but if user declines location permission the second parameter is the one that's gonna handle that

Comment: instead of saying it needs two parameters, just say add the optional error callback to handle the error.

Comment: edited..
anyways you are gonna fetch for location on every state change !!!
just pointing there

Comment: editted code, it threw the following error with url removed: 
message: "Network location provider at 'google api url': No response received."

Comment: this is related to Chrome's internal api key used for google maps geo location running out of daily quota

Comment: Yes I am using chrome, on safari I am getting 'Access to geolocation was blocked over insecure connection to http://localhost:3000' I have allowed location services for local host. Also, isn't the api geolocation limit for googleapi large, say over 100? I am not sure. I have only done it a handful of times today, maybe 10 or so.

Comment: try Mozilla for once... same api key might be present in another device's chrome...  repeated request might be cause of quota exhaustion..

Comment: one question !!!
are you limiting useEffect to first render only or not ?

Comment: I am trying Mozilla I will update once I have downloaded it, and yes I did limit it to first render with [ ] as second argument for useEffect. Yesterday, I used componentDidMount before proceeding by implementing the ip-api.

Comment: I checked chrome today and was able to get the geolocation, so I had exceed my googleapi limit. Thanks again Excalibur.